# What version of Ubuntu is most efficient and stable as a small-scale server?

Tags: server, versions

I have a fairly old desktop with a [Pentium 4](http://ark.intel.com/products/27497/Intel-Pentium-4-Processor-supporting-HT-Technology-3_00-GHz-1M-Cache-800-MHz-FSB) and 1GB of RAM. I use it as a TeamSpeak server and to browse the web, not a lot of heavy-duty stuff, although I am considering building a website, in which case I would use it as a server. I currently run Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. I tried the server version once but the installation process took too long and it wasn't absolutely necessary.

Recently, the hard disk drive suffered a failure and lost data, so I will re-install Ubuntu. Given the hardware and purpose, is 14.04.2 LTS enough, or does the server version really bring more to the table? Or is 15.04 a great improvement, especially performance-wise?

Overall, my question is this: Running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS with a GUI as a small-scale server on an old system, is the server version or the desktop version more efficient in terms of required processing power?

Comment: This question barely passes the 'Asking for Opinions' check because you ask for a comparison of what would work.  However, you are still asking for an opinionated answer, and that's not really on par for the site despite my answer below.

Comment: @Clefspeare13 when referencing software, use the fully established name - 'TS' could mean TeamSpeak, time stamp, timeshare, etc. so using fully established software names is more prudent.  As well, what do you mean by "and to browse"?

Comment: Ok, my bad. By browse I mean the web, I use Firefox, so a GUI is necessary,.

Comment: @Clefspeare13 OK, I included that consideration in my analysis below.  However I would consider getting a newer desktop for GUI stuff - that hardware is pretty old for GUI stuff.  Flash games would be slow on that hardware, even, hence my suggestion there.  But I did include all this in my analysis.

Comment: Your question is really three different questions.  Please post one question per question, as that works better for this site format.  Also, what research have you done?  Finally, for future reference, I encourage you to read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask.  Note the discussion about subjective questions and about doing your research and showing it in the question.

Comment: Your question is really wide

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are asking different questions essentially, and are also requesting an opinion.

Let's split these analyses up then I'll add my two cents.

---

#### Desktop vs. Server Edition

Which do you want to work with more, a GUI or a command line?  Better question, do you want to deal with the overhead of a graphical interface which will need memory cycles and video memory to run (in addition to the extra software you want to run)?  Another question: Do you need the GUI for Firefox or a web browser?

If all you are running are server processes I would ditch the GUI and use the Server variant instead.  This recommendation is based on the need of graphical interfaces vs. my knowledge of the command line.  Most of what servers need is on the command line. The Server edition doesn't come with a GUI installed and is command line driven compared to GUI driven (the GUI is just a graphical front end to run the commands the terminal would need transparently).

If you need the computer for Internet browsing and things which need the graphical environment (line word processors, spreadsheet stuff, etc.) as well, then don't use Server variant, just install the relevant server processes alongside the GUI.  Lubuntu will be the 'quickest' GUI for those specs as its lightest weight compared to the other variants.

---

#### LTS or Newer Release (Non-LTS)

This is an easier question to answer in my opinion.

The **LTS** (14.04 currently) has a 5 year support cycle, meaning it gets security updates and patches for five years from its release date.  The trade off is that you don't get newer software versions (typically).  You trade cutting edge software (and newer features in them) for stability.

The **non-LTS** releases have a ***much shorter*** support period.  This means you will need to upgrade to a new OS version very frequently.  With each upgrade you run the risk of more things exploding.  After the support period ends you get no more security updates or bug fix patches for that release, and have to upgrade.  The trade off is that you get newer software versions but may sacrifice the stability of operation / version change differences and having to adapt software for each set of changes.

I suggest using the LTS regardless of Server or Desktop edition.

---

#### Performance Comparison between 14.04 and 15.04

I have no basis for comparison.  However, the GUI will be just as slow in 14.04 vs. 15.04 and will operate at similar speeds.  (this applies to 14.10 as well but as that EOLs in a couple months I would not use it)  Use Lubuntu with the LXDE environment for the lightest GUI (it won't lag or be slow as much compared to Unity on Ubuntu).

The server software will run about equally fast between 14.04 and 15.04.  The huge main difference between 14.04 and 15.04 is the init system - systemd is in 15.04 as primary instead of upstart as the primary.  The other big comparison point is the kernel version as well as the software versions available in each release.

However, for just server functions, both will operate about equally well compared to each other.

---

#### My Opinion

If all you're running on this is server processes, like TeamSpeak server or a file server, and nothing large scale, it's up to you.  However, I would suggest using 14.04 LTS Server.

I suggest this because stability of software version will likely be more useful than upgrading every new release.  I also suggest this because the graphics overhead is nonexistent and you have more resources freed up to the system and server processes.

If you want a GUI though, use Lubuntu 14.04 which has the LXDE GUI which is relatively lightweight compared to Ubuntu or the other variants.  It also will likely get core security updates for 5 years as well.

You should consider using newer equipment for GUI stuff, though.  GUIs are fine and all, but they add additional attack vectors on servers, and with the hardware you have listed GUIs will still likely be slower than on newer, more updated, hardware.

Comment: Note on this answer: this does not take into account nitty-gritty things like kernel level specialization and optimization for server vs desktop, or much more technical bits, it's just a general overview of the differences with a recommendation.  It is not intended to nitpick the technical nuances between server and desktop versions.

Comment: To complement this answer, to OP, I would suggest reading up on server deployments, so that you could deploy a pre-configured server instance on a virtual machine. This makes things so much easier to maintain, e.g. "oh, a new version of Ubuntu is available? Let's just edit the script and specify the new version, build the new VM, pause the previous VM (optional, depends on how far you are willing to make your setup redundant), test it, and once we're satisified, make it the default VM and decommission the old VM, or if there are issues, restore the old VM." …

Comment: … Running a VM gives you a few advantages, including easier maintainability, portability (limited to host's support of VM technology) and not running a GUI. But I do agree that virtualization support for a Pentium 4 might not be to par with more modern processors. You may consider technologies like containers instead (lxc, Docker…). Containers also lend themselves very well to the "build → test → migrate" workflow.

Comment: @sebleblanc While somewhat accurate, virtualization on the hardware they specified would run really slow and inefficiently on the system.  It would drastically slow down the ability for the host to operate as expected.  I wouldn't try and virtualize anything in the OP's case because you end up with a double NAT situation.

Comment: I agree 100%, that is why I also mention alternatives like containers. Containers allow you to build "repeatable deployments" without the overhead of virtualization (with some drawbacks). Re: NAT, for instance Docker allows you to bind container ports to your local machine, thus avoiding NAT. (it will simply setup `iptables` rules for you)

Comment: In theory that's still virtualization, even with Docker, no?

Comment: [Actually, it's not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization). It's batched in 'virtualization' since it's a solution for the same type of problem, but actually containers are like `chroot`s on steroids. In a nutshell, it's a kernel-level feature that provides isolation between UID/GID, process spaces and filesystem mounts. Only a small set of components in containers are emulated, e.g. virtual network interfaces. The cool thing about containers is that they will work without performance issues on any platform that can run your kernel.